# Compare value and return a bool in Swift

Tags: swift, boolean

I am converting my code from Objective-C to Swift. I declared a function to compare values of two properties and return a `Bool`.
And I am confused about why this code not work in Swift.

```
private var currentLineRange: NSRange?
var location: UInt?

func atBeginningOfLine() -> Bool {
    return self.location! == self.currentLineRange?.location ? true : false
}
```

Compiler gave me an error:

> Could not find an overload for == that accepts the supplied arguments

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using the redundant `? true : false`? The value to the left of `?` is *already* a `Bool`. Just return it.

Comment: @GregHewgill Oh, your are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two optional values and you want to check if they’re equal.  There is a version of `==` for comparing two optionals – but they need to be of the same type.

The main problem here is that you are comparing `NSRange.location`, which is a `Int`, with `location`, which is a `UInt`.  If you tried to do this even without the complication of the optionals, you’d get an error:

```
let ui: UInt = 1
let i: Int = 1
// error: binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of 
// type 'Int' and ‘UInt'
i == ui
```

There’s two ways you can go.  Either change `location` to be an `Int`, and you’ll be able to use the optional `==`:

```
private var currentLineRange: NSRange?
var location: Int?

func atBeginningOfLine() -> Bool {
    // both optionals contain Int, so you can use == on them:
    return location == currentLineRange?.location
}
```

Or, if `location` really does need to be a `UInt` for some other reason, `map` one of the optionals to the type of the other to compare them:

```
private var currentLineRange: NSRange?
var location: UInt?

func atBeginningOfLine() -> Bool {
    return location.map { Int($0) } == currentLineRange?.location
}
```

One thing to be careful of – `nil` is equal to `nil`.  So if you don’t want this (depends on the logic you’re going for), you need to code for it explicitly:

```
func atBeginningOfLine() -> Bool {
    if let location = location, currentLineRange = currentLineRange {
        // assuming you want to stick with the UInt
        return Int(location) == currentLineRange.location
    }
    return false // if either or both are nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift has operator overloading, so == is a function. You have to define a function that takes your two types.

If you remove the UInt it works:

```
class Document {
    private var currentLineRange: NSRange?
    var location: Int?

    func atBeginningOfLine() -> Bool {
        if let currentLocation = self.location, lineRange = self.currentLineRange {
            return currentLocation=lineRange?.location
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Modified to be null safe.

Comment: if both values are nil it will return true

Comment: `func NSMakeRange(loc: Int, len: Int) -> NSRange` I should have see this `len` is an `int` type. :)

Comment: @LeoDabus I of course agree the if let is better but I was trying to answer THIS question not make the optimal version of this function.

Comment: @Wongzigii love operator overloading, had to get used to this myself, hadn't used it since C++ a LONG time ago!